# Term for competitor that is not the favourite

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

In a betting sport such as horse racing or boxing, the competitor for whom the odds are lowest is known as the *favourite*.

Can the other competitors be termed something in contrast?

Comment: Underdog, outsider, challenger, long shot.

Comment: But in fairness, in boxing (**if you mean just one bout, not a series**), there's only one other in "the field", which could affect the answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If one competitor is the *favorite*, the other is the *underdog*.

Comment: That's not for just anyone who's not a favourite, though, but one who is specifically expected _not_ to have a chance of winning. In a field of eight race horses, one might be the favourite, one or two might be underdogs—and the rest are neither.

Comment: I was under the impression that _underdog_ referred to the least favourite in a competition as @JanusBahsJacquet says, but Wiktionary bears out the definition of any competitor that is not the favourite.

In any case, Dan Bron's answer certainly fits the case I was primarily thinking of, as in a one-on-one competition.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underdog#Noun

Comment: @william.berg Where? It says specifically there that the underdog is “a competitor _thought unlikely to win_” (my emphasis). That excludes the middle of the field who aren't favourites to win, but won't shock if they do, either.

Comment: By definition, the favourite is thought most likely to win, and all other competitors were thought unlikely to win.

Comment: you've misspelled *favourite*.

Comment: Note that *underdog* is usually (but by no means always) used of the less favoured competitor in one-on-one competitions: ***the** underdog* is far more common than ***an** underdog*.

Comment: underdog is the **opposite of favourite**. it's that simple.  I believe the OP is simply asking for the "rest of the field", is there a word for "the non-favourites" (which set would include any underdog(s)).

Comment: @Jodrell: *favorite* is a perfectly correct spelling.

Answer (score 30):

Competitors below the favourite or favourites are *the field*. Least-favoured competitors, for whom *long odds* are quoted by bookmakers, are *long shots*, and a winner who was given little or no chance of winning is a *dark horse*.

Comment: Actually, I think *dark horse* simply means it is less known to the bettors. Usually that also implies it has long odds but it's not always the case - only that it is an unknown entity.

Comment: @congusbongus, That's my understanding as well. The dark horse is the wild card, that nobody (or at least, few people) are certain about. `define:"dark horse"` on Google suggests that the dark horse is both little-known _and_ ends up as the winner.

Comment: Upvoted for all information provided except "dark horse" for the reasons already given by congusbongus above.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it's sad that people voted for a word that is so obviously not what was asked.

Comment: "I never bet on the favourite: I always bet on the field." This works for horse racing, but what about boxing?

Answer (score 8):

Sticking with betting terminology you could also say "outsider" if the odds against are high.

Or "less fancied" runner.

Comment: Also common in betting terminology is the [***long shot***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/long+shot). And a *really* long odds outsider might be called a ***rank outsider***. I don't know why someone downvoted this well-focussed answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thanks. As the DV was simultaneous with the removal of another (negatively voted) answer on this question that I had commented on I suspect it was not given for any particularly good/relevant motivation!

Comment: The word you are looking for is *Outsider* or *outsiders*. *Dark horse* is one that's not obviously towards the front end of the betting or coming in under the radar but many think has the potential to surprise.

Answer (score 8):

> The *contender*

Especially in human one-on-one sports, such as boxing.

> The *field*

Or the rest of the field, can be used to describe the rest of the non-favourite horses in a horse race.

Comment: Contender does not mean unfavoured to win. It just means competitor. A contender for the title of boxing champion is one who competes for that title. The contender, or challenger, is not necessarily the one with less odds of winning.

Answer (score 3):

First things to come to mind are *cannon fodder* and *also rans*.

*Also rans* implies the race is over, but I've heard it used to describe competitors that are not expected to place.

*Cannon fodder* is probably a bit more mean spirited, but gives a sense of providing enough members in the race, but of lesser quality.

Answer (score 2):

*Not a contender* or *long shot* are terms used to describe fringe competitors.

To be in *the middle of the pack* is another term for competitors who are not the favorite to win.